# How to extract values from time series database written from Prometheus to Influxdb

Tags: sql, influxdb, prometheus

hi i need help on how to actually view values being written to the database, no matter what i do i cant seem to get at the actually numbers.

I cant seem to write a influxdb query that will return actual values, ive been at it for hours.

I am trying to validate that certain data is being written into a influxdb database.

My setup **node_exporter** sends data to **prometheus** which then writes to an **Influxdb** database.

I have confirmed data node_exporter is sending the data, and prometheus is capturing it. On prometheus I am able to run query and get results:

```
tcp_count_by_http_2019{apache_component="category1",apache_rpc="category2"} 93983
```

jumping on the influxdb i am able to see a ton of data by executing

```
show series
```

but the output is to huge for me to validate the part of data i need. As ouput scrolls passed i can see labels from what i saw in the prometheus gui, and i have graphs that successfully pull in most of the data from influxdb so i know metrics are going in.

In Influxdb:

I ran the below with confirms the correct keys and fields are in the database but i want to view the value stored for the below.

```
> show tag keys on "test_influxdb"
name: _
tagKey
------
apache_component
apache_rpc

> show tag values on "test_influxdb" with key = "blaze_rpc" limit 5
name: _
key       value
---       -----
apache_component category1
apache_component category3
apache_rpc category2
apache_rpc category4

> show field keys
name: _
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
f64      float
```

Hopefully the above is enough to explain what I am after. I want to look up these values show below in bold.

*tcp_count_by_http_2019{apache_component="category1",apache_rpc="category2"} **93983***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tcp_count_by_http_2019
WHERE apache_component = 'category1' AND apache_rpc='category2'
```

Comment: Thank you, youre awesome! The above almost work the "tcp_count_by_http_2019" is at the prometheus level and not in the database, but its 95%

This worked: `SELECT * FROM _
WHERE apache_component = 'category1' AND apache_rpc='category2'`